# How to get an array of values based on an array of indexes?

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I have a set of two arrays. One contains some fruit values as strings, the other one contains some random numbers. Here I considered the number arrays are the indexes of the fruits array. How to get a new array of fruits given the numbers in the index array?

Sample code:

```
var resultArr = [];
var fruitier = ["apple", "orange", "grapes", "pineapple", "fig", "banana", "jackfruit", "pomegranate"];
var indexArr = [0, 2, 4];
```

Output:

```
resultArr = ["apple", "grapes", "fig"];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for(var i = 0; i < indexArr.length; i++)
  resultArr.push(fruitier[indexArr[i]]);
```

Answer (score 59):

Use [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
let resultArr = indexArr.map(i => fruitier[i])
```

Answer (score 12):

If you want to achieve that with lodash, use [`_.at()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.6#at):

```js
var fruitier = ['apple', 'orange', 'grapes', 'pineapple', 'fig', 'banana', 'jackfruit', 'pomegranate'];
var indexArr = [0, 2, 4];
var resultArr = _.at(fruitier, indexArr);

console.log(resultArr);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.16.6/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Just be aware that if you use flow type, it will complain because `_.at()` expects the first argument to be of Object, not Array. I think it's fine to ignore it using `// $FlowFixMe`

Answer (score 1):

Array#map works ([documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/map))

```
const getFromIndex = (array, indexes) => indexes.map((index) => array[index]);
```

You can use Array#filter too ([documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter))

```
const fruitier = ['apple', 'orange', 'grapes', 'pineapple', 'fig',   'banana', 'jackfruit', 'pomegranate'];
const indexArr = [0, 2, 4];  

const getFromIndex = (array, indexes) => {
  return array.filter((element, index) => indexes.includes(index)); 
};
```

Or also Array#reduce ([documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/reduce))

```
const getFromIndex = (array, indexes) => {
    return indexes.reduce((result, i) => result.concat(array[i]), []); 
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Use lodash [pullAt](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#pullAt)

```
var fruitier = ["apple", "orange", "grapes", "pineapple", "fig", "banana", 
"jackfruit", "pomegranate"];
var indexArr = [0, 2, 4];
var resultArr = _.pullAt(fruitier, indexArr);
console.log(resultArr);
// ["apple", "grapes", "fig"]
```

`<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>`

Key difference to be aware of alongside the above recommendation for _.at() is - this method mutates input array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `for..of` loop

```
for (var key of indexArr) resultArr[resultArr.length] = fruitier[key];
```